# Finding remainder of stepping by multiple beyond a limit

Tags: javascript

**Summary**: Looking for more elegant version of `Math.ceil(a/b)*b - a`.

I'm writing code (QML Canvas) that draws a timeline, with tick marks every *n* pixels.

```
// Stepping across the width of the window, drawing tick marks
for (var x=0; x<windowWidth; x+=n) drawTickAndLabelAt(x);
```

The timeline can be scrolled such that time=0 moves off the left edge of the window. I need to figure out the correct `x` value to start at so that the ticks are still drawn at the same time. That value is the multiple of *n* that is just larger than the scroll offset, minus the scroll offset.

This is the naive representation of that formula:

```
var firstTickX = Math.ceil(scrollOffset/n)*n - scrollOffset;
for (var x=firstTickX; x<windowWidth; x+=n) drawTickAndLabelAt(x);
```

This works, but the formula feels inelegant, referencing both variables twice. Can you think of a simpler code path (using modulus, I'm assuming) that I'm failing to think of?

Comment: `b - (a%b || b)` ?

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the terseness. You should make this an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Math.ceil(scrollOffset/n)*n - scrollOffset
```

gives you the difference between `scrollOffset` and the next multiple of `n` larger or equal to `scrollOffset`. This is equivalent to:

```
var firstTickX = (scrollOffset % n) ? n - (scrollOffset % n) : 0;
```

Comment: Close. Notice the edge case @wOxxOm accounted for in the comment above.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I updated the answer to catch this case by using the ternary operator.

Comment: You've fixed the edge case when `scrollOffset` is 0, but not the edge case when `scrollOffset` is a perfect multiple of `n`, e.g. `scrollOffset=81` and `n=9` should result in `0`, not `9`.

Comment: How embarrassing. You're right. I changed the condition to include these cases.